# Как передать ресурс из одного фрагмента в другой?

Tags: java, android, android-fragment, textview

В одном фрагменте есть кнопки, по нажатию которых открывается другой

```
    btn1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.container, textFragment).commit();
        }
    });

    btn2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.container, textFragment).commit();
        }
    });
```

В другом фрагменте

```
TextView text = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.text);
```

и в этот `TextView` нужно добавить текст из ресурса в зависимости от того, что было нажато. Если `btn1`, то `R.string.b1`, если `btn2`, то `R.string.b2`. Как это лучше сделать? Кнопок много и не хочется создавать для каждой фрагмент - это глупо.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вашу задачу можно решить несколькими способами. Вот один из них

Создаем utils класс.

```
public class FragmentUtils {

    public static void replaceFragment(FragmentActivity activity, Fragment fragment) {
        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction;
        fragmentTransaction = activity.getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.content_main, fragment);
        fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);
        fragmentTransaction.commit();
    }
}
```

И через Bundle будем передовать ID нашей строки или сразу String(решать вам), которую нужно отобразить.

Это может выглядеть вот так:

```
        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        bundle.putInt("ID", R.string.app_name);
        TextFragment textFragment = new TextFragment();
        adapterCvodkaFragment.setArguments(bundle);
        FragmentUtils.replaceFragment(this, textFragment);
```

В методе onCreateView() вашего фрагменты получаете ID вашей строки.

```
Bundle bundle = getArguments();

    if (bundle != null) {
        id = bundle.getInt("ID);
    }
```

И передаете уже вашему TextView